# Reading 4mc extension files from HDFS in Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I want to read [4mc](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc) files from HDFS into Spark environment to process using Java.

I realized that the entry point for spark is SparkSession. How to load the data into DataSet using SparkSession from HDFS?

Comment: [this link in the same repo showcases how to use it with Spark(Java)](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc/blob/master/java/examples/src/main/java/com/hadoop/fourmc/spark/protobuf/TestProtobufInput.java)

Comment: I want to create a DataSet directly instead of JavaRDD and from there whatever I need.